# Apache camel getting error while passing an Xml as payload and trying to marshal it to json

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I am using POSTMan for testing my API, i'm trying to pass an xml (type: application/xml)through postman to my rest api endpoint. I want to read this xml and then store the corresponding information in my database.

I'm trying to first convert the xml to json through camel and then read the data and insert it. I've defined the routings correctly (i think so), but i'm always getting the following error:

`"{ \"status\": 400, \"message\": \"an error occurred: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@18eaa21b; line: 1, column: 2]\" }`"

The xml which i'm sending is:

```
    <ns1:ContractLinkEvent xmlns:ns1="some url" xmlns:ns0="some url"><Header xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Action>UPDATE</Action>
        <SubAction2 xsi:nil="true" />
        <SourceSystemUser xsi:nil="true" />
      </Header><ContractLink xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SourceId>c4eb36da-4db7-e811-80ed-0050568e7b74</SourceId>
        <ContractLinkId>1509148</ContractLinkId>
        <PricingAgreement>
          <SourceId>86078759-49b7-e811-80ed-0050568e7b74</SourceId>
          <PricingAgreementId>1509146</PricingAgreementId>
          <ContractCode>C000012151</ContractCode>
          <Currency>USD</Currency>
          <ReferenceNumber>REF.012002</ReferenceNumber>
          <CreateDate>2018-09-13T11:37:10Z</CreateDate>
          <CreateUser>username</CreateUser>
          <CreateSystem>CRM</CreateSystem>
          <ModifiedDate>2018-09-13T12:02:42Z</ModifiedDate>
          <ModifiedUser>username</ModifiedUser>
          <ModifiedSystem>CRM</ModifiedSystem>
        </PricingAgreement>
        <BillingProfile>
          <SourceId>409cfdd9-781b-e511-b242-0050568e4f04</SourceId>
          <BillingProfileId>173886</BillingProfileId>
          <BillingProfileCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <BillingProfileName xsi:nil="true" />
          <DisplayName xsi:nil="true" />
          <BillingProfileTypeCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <SellingLE xsi:nil="true" />
          <APCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <PrimaryBillingFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <BillToCreditCardFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <PrintPriorityCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <InvoiceTypeCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <ElectronicInvoiceCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <PaperInvoiceCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <InvoiceFormat xsi:nil="true" />
          <ItemizedInvoiceFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <DeliveryMethodCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <InvoiceEmailAddress xsi:nil="true" />
          <InvoiceEmailContactName xsi:nil="true" />
          <CompressionFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <CompressionPassword xsi:nil="true" />
          <PaperInvoiceFeeFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <BusinessCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <VatNumber xsi:nil="true" />
          <MinimumBillingFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <VesselSortFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <AllowReguideFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <AllowRerateFlag xsi:nil="true" />
          <CreateUser xsi:nil="true" />
          <CreateSystem xsi:nil="true" />
          <ModifiedUser xsi:nil="true" />
          <ModifiedSystem xsi:nil="true" />
          <SalesOrg xsi:nil="true" />
          <DistChannel xsi:nil="true" />
          <Division xsi:nil="true" />
          <SalesDistrictCode xsi:nil="true" />
          <SalesOffice xsi:nil="true" />
          <Currency xsi:nil="true" />
          <PaymentTerms xsi:nil="true" />
          <DPId xsi:nil="true" />
          <BillingProfileGroup xsi:nil="true" />
          <InvoiceEmailList xsi:nil="true" />
          <SV xsi:nil="true" />
          <SAP xsi:nil="true" />
          <ServiceProfiles xsi:nil="true" />
          <SAPBlock xsi:nil="true" />
          <ContractClasses xsi:nil="true" />
        </BillingProfile>
        <StartDate>2018-09-16T00:00:00</StartDate>
        <CreateDate>2018-09-13T12:09:28Z</CreateDate>
        <CreateUser>Pratiksha Gupta</CreateUser>
        <CreateSystem>CRM</CreateSystem>
        <ModifiedDate>2018-09-13T12:11:23Z</ModifiedDate>
        <ModifiedUser>sv-CRMAPProxy AP Proxy</ModifiedUser>
        <ModifiedSystem>CRM</ModifiedSystem>
      </ContractLink></ns1:ContractLinkEvent>
```

I've verified the xml online and there are no errors in the xml. I've also defined the routing in camel for the endpoint:

```
rest("/readXml")
        .consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .post()
        //.outType(String.class)
                .to("direct:readxml");

        from("direct:readxml").streamCaching()
                .process(readAndInsertXml)
                 .marshal().xmljson() 

                 .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST")) 
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/xml"))
                .to("mock:result").end();
```

This is my readandInsertXml Processor which is empty for now.

```
@Component
public class ReadAndInsertXml implements Processor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    /*  SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();*/
        try {
            logger.info("inside processor method of read xml");
            logger.info(exchange.getIn().getBody().toString());
/*          Document doc = (Document) exchange.getIn().getBody();
            logger.info("after storing in dom document");
            System.out.println(doc.getAttributes())*/;
            exchange.getOut().setBody("sample");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've searched online for multiple times, but i can't find a solution. Can anyone help here what am i doing wrong

Comment: Hi @Anurag. I don't understand why you are trying to convert to json - and appear to be trying to do it twice (before the setHeader and again after). It sounds like you're trying to parse json and giving the parser XML hence it complains. Why are you getting the body, and using `toString` rather than getting the body as a DOM document? `getBody( org.w3c.dom.Document.class )`

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake while writing the question. There is no marshal method after set header

Comment: That's the problem, it thinks that i' tryin to parse json when in reality i'm sending an xml

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was with the rest binding configuration, i had to change it from json to auto.